# How can I display data in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to display data from database in the cards, but it show empty, is there any solution to fix my problem?
here is it my output, I want to display data in these empty cards

[image]

MY TS:

```
listSousCategorie: any[]=[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.Getsouscatégorie();
  }
  closemodal() {
    this.dialogRef.close({
      submitted: false
    });
  }
  Getsouscatégorie(){
    this. ExamenSouCategorieService.findAll().then((res)=>{
      this.listSousCategorie = res.map(function (obj:any) {
        return {
          value: obj.id,
          label: obj.libelle
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

MY HTML:

```
 <mat-expansion-panel class="childPanel childPanelCount" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled>
          <p>Nombre des sous catégories {{listSousCategorie.length}}</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie">

          <mat-expansion-panel class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled>
            <p>{{i.libelle}}</p>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
```

My Model:

```
export class SousCategorie {
  public id: number;
  public code: string;
  public libelle: string='';
  public coefficient: string;
  public Note: string;
  public id_categorie: string;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the result you get from the back-end to objects of this shape:

```
{
  value: number;
  label: string;
}
```

You should render the `value` property inside your `<p>` to get the desired result:

```html
<p>{{i.value}}</p>
```

Or, you could remove the `map` call and use the objects you get from the back-end directly:

```
  Getsouscatégorie(){
    this.ExamenSouCategorieService.findAll().then((res)=>{
      this.listSousCategorie = res;
    });
```